# How do you modify query to include additional fields in the results?

Tags: ms-access

I have the following MS Access query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [cnPart],[desc] as DATA,"desc" as CAT from PartData
UNION SELECT [cnPart], [qty], "qty" FROM PartData
UNION SELECT [cnPart], [matl],"matl" FROM PartData
UNION SELECT [cnPart], [spec],"spec" FROM PartData)  AS A
WHERE (((A.[cnPart]) In ('00001','00002','00003','00004','00005')));
```

which returns this data:

```
|---------------------------|
|cnPart |DATA       |CAT    |
|---------------------------|
|00001  |10         |qty    |
|00001  |a4b7c3d4   |spe    |
|00001  |blWidget   |desc   |
|00001  |s1         |matl   |
|00002  |20         |qty    |
|00002  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   |
|00002  |brWidget   |desc   |
|00002  |s1         |matl   |
|00003  |15         |qty    |
|00003  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   |
|00003  |gnWidget   |desc   |
|00003  |s1         |matl   |
|00004  |5          |qty    |
|00004  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   |
|00004  |rdWidget   |desc   |
|00004  |s1         |matl   |
|00005  |30         |qty    |
|00005  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   |
|00005  |s1         |matl   |
|00005  |vtWidget   |desc   |
|---------------------------|
```

I want to remove the rows where there are duplicates in the `DATA` column, so the result would look like this:

```
|---------------------------|
|cnPart |DATA       |CAT    |
|---------------------------|
|00001  |10         |qty    |
|00001  |blWidget   |desc   |
|00002  |20         |qty    |
|00002  |brWidget   |desc   |
|00003  |15         |qty    |
|00003  |gnWidget   |desc   |
|00004  |5          |qty    |
|00004  |rdWidget   |desc   |
|00005  |30         |qty    |
|00005  |vtWidget   |desc   |
|---------------------------|
```

Rows which contain duplicates in the `DATA` column have been removed.  The duplicate data in this case is `S1` and `a4b7c3d4`.

So far, I have managed to cobble together this:

```
SELECT A.data
FROM (SELECT [cnPart],[desc] as DATA,"desc" as CAT from PartData
UNION SELECT [cnPart], [qty], "qty" FROM PartData
UNION SELECT [cnPart], [matl],"matl" FROM PartData
UNION SELECT [cnPart], [spec],"spec" FROM PartData)  AS A
WHERE (A.cnPart In ('00001','00002','00003','00004','00005'))
GROUP BY A.data
HAVING (Count(A.data)=1);
```

however the issue is that it doesn't return the `cnPart` and `CAT` columns.

If I modify the query to contain these columns in the `SELECT` statement, I don't get anything back at all.

How can I modify this to include these additional columns?

Thanks

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: @mustaccio - I'm not sure what you're inferring? Having looked at the suggestions, I have written a clear explanation, I have provided sample data, I have described the expected results and I have shown what I already have...  If I have missed something, what specifically have I missed?